# Force matplotlibrc to use Arial (path of font)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, seaborn

I have Arial font installed in my system:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbi.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arial.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ariali.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Italic.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Black.ttf
/usr/share/xbmc/media/Fonts/arial.ttf
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/urw/arial
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/afm/urw/arial
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/vf/urw/arial
/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/type1/urw/arial
```

I have changed inside my matplotlibrc including the line:

```
font.sans-serif      : Arial
```

If I check inside IPython:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,], '*')
t = plt.ylabel(r'1, 2, 3, 8, 9 6 11 Testing Label')
print(t.get_fontname())
```

The output is:

```
myhome/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2-py2.7-linux-
x86_64.egg/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1279: UserWarning: findfont: Font
family [u'sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
(prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Bitstream Vera Sans
```

How can I change this behavior and use Arial fonts for all of my plots?
Why Arial font is not loaded?

It is interesting, that if I use Seaborn, it returns `Liberation Sans` where the first font (inside internal font list) is Arial and the second is `Liberation Sans`.

Comment: It would seem your question was answered on the matplotlib mailing list by Benjamin Root. Solution: "delete the font cache (usually in ~/.matplotlib). Fonts installed after matplotlib is first used are often never recognized."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by @BenjaminRoot to delete the font cache on `~/.matplotlib`

In fact in my Debian system, with python stuff inside virtualenv ecosystem, such folder was located at `~/.cache/matplotlib/`
I have deleted all files and folder and the cache was regenerated again.
Now it works! =]