# Setting a custom font in Matplotlib using rcParams

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, ubuntu-14.04

There have been many threads on this already ([Force matplotlibrc to use Arial (path of font)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053488/force-matplotlibrc-to-use-arial-paht-of-font), [How to load .ttf file in matplotlib using mpl.rcParams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574898/how-to-load-ttf-file-in-matplotlib-using-mpl-rcparams)). None seems to help in my case. I have number of fonts installed on my system and registered in matplotlib. Everything seems to work when I am in the shell:

```
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> from matplotlib import font_manager
>>> path = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Times_New_Roman.ttf'
>>> props = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)
>>> print props
family=Times New Roman ... file=/usr/.../Times_New_Roman.ttf ...
>>> mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = props.get_name()
>>> mpl.rcParams
RcParams({...,u'font.family': [u'Times New Roman'], ... })
```

However, when I try to do the same in a script and run it (and I have tried a dozen times), I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1282: UserWarning: findfont: Font family [u'Times New Roman'] not found.
```

Why?

Comment: Try displaying the version numbers in both cases, e.g. `print mpl.__version__, sys.version`

Comment: I am running mpl 1.4.3 and Python 2.7.6. These versions are reported in both cases. Btw. I have tried to run the same script with Anaconda on Win 7 and it works perfectly fine.