# Matplotlib cannot find sans-serif family

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, gentoo

This code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams.update({
    'font.family':'sans-serif',
    'font.sans-serif':['Helvetica'],
    })

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.matshow(np.random.rand(16,16))

plt.show()
```

gives me the following warning:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1288: UserWarning: 
findfont: Font family [u'sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
(prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

I have checked and I have Helvetica installed:

```
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO18-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO12.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvR24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB14.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvB24.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO10.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvBO18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO14-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO08-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/helvO10-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Oblique
```

I have also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053488/force-matplotlibrc-to-use-arial-path-of-font), and I have repeatedly deleted `fontList.cache`, but to no avail.

How can I change my font to Helvetica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this was because my fonts were `.pcf` and you need `.ttf` to actually write with them. due to licensing issues, at least under Gentoo, there is no Helvetica available via the package manager.

My solution was to install `media-fonts/liberation-fonts` which is the Gentoo package for the Liberation Fonts.
Liberation Sans is a fairly good stand-in for Helvetica.

The following code snippet basically fixed my example:

```
rcParams.update({
    'font.family':'sans-serif',
    'font.sans-serif':['Liberation Sans'],
    })
```